# C'è qualche differenza di pronuncia della "s" tra "chiuso" e "frase"?

Tags: difference, pronunciation

Ho cominciato un corso d'italiano in cui ho fatto un esercizio orale. La mia insegnante mi ha fatto vedere che non sempre riesco a pronunciare bene la "s" intervocalica. In particolare, in questo esercizio non ho pronunciato bene "uccisione", "chiuso", "basato", "tesi", "frase" e "così". Se ho capito bene, il problema è che ho pronunciato la "s" sorda, ma dovrebbe essere sonora. Tuttavia, una ricerca di questi vocaboli sul [dizionario d’ortografia e di pronunzia della RAI](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/ricerca.aspx)
sembra indicare che la pronuncia della "s" di "chiuso" sia diversa da quella delle altre parole dell'elenco. È così? Cioè, la "s" di "chiuso" è sorda e non sonora?

Comment: Hai ragione: il dizionario di ortografia e di pronunzia della RAI usa una s sorda. Non capisco perché però, io uso e sento usare solo una s sonora, sia di persona che in tv o alla radio.

Comment: Il rilievo può dipendere dalle origini dell'insegnante: ci sono notevoli differenze tra le diverse regioni. Per esempio 'così' con O aperta o chiusa, oppure la S pronunciata quasi come SC.

Comment: Penso che sia una cosa regionale, @DenisNardin. Mi sembra che in Toscana e forse anche Lazio sia normale la s sorda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nell'italiano standard (quello derivato dal fiorentino) la s sorda e quella sonora – cioè, nell'IPA, /s/ e /z/ – sono due fonemi diversi. Esistono infatti “coppie minime”, come per esempio “chie[s]e” (passato di chiedere) e “chie[z]e” (edifici di culto).

Questa differenza in varie parti d'Italia non è però sentita. Per citare l'[*Enciclopedia dell'italiano*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sibilanti_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/):

> Emblematico è il comportamento della coppia fonematica /s z/ il cui rendimento funzionale, tutt’altro che elevato, subisce forti restrizioni. L’opposizione tra /s/ e /z/ vige infatti solo in posizione intervocalica: per es. [ˈkjɛːse] (passato remoto del verbo chiedere) ~ [ˈkjɛːze] (plur. di chiesa), e solo sul territorio toscano. Nel resto d’Italia si ha una vera scissione di esiti: nelle varietà settentrionali si ha solo /z/, in gran parte del Centro-Sud solo /s/.

Quindi, se vuoi imparare un italiano standard corretto, fa' caso alla distinzione fra i due suoni; se no, poco male, e se ne accorgeranno solo in alcune parti del centro Italia.

Delle parole menzionate nella domanda, in italiano standard “chiuso” e “così” hanno la s sorda, tutte le altre quella sonora. Il DOP è spesso utile, ma queste indicazioni sono presenti in tutti i dizionari, qualche volta usando l'IPA, altre volte usando altre notazioni (per esempio una “s” normale per /s/ e una s con un puntino sopra per /z/).

Comment: In realtà anche noi del nord sentiamo bene la differenza tra [s] e [z], per esempio in veneto (la lingua) il fonema [s] è usato spesso dove in italiano si userebbe [ss] (la doppia s), e quindi in contrapposizione con la [z]. Detto questo la cosa peggiore che succede scambiandoli è che uno suoni "foresto" (straniero).

Comment: Ma, nell'italiano standard, il suono della "s" di "chiuso" è sordo oppure sonoro?

Comment: Sembra che questi aspetti siano importanti per la parte orale dell'esame che dovrò fare alla fine del corso (livello C1).

Comment: Grazie, @Charo, corretto. E ho anche completato la risposta.

Comment: Hai ragione: anche il DOP indica una "s" sorda per "così"!

Comment: @DaG dovrebbero essere scritte *cossì, *chiusso, *chiesse? C'è da qualche parte una lista de parole dove -s- è /s/, o non è così semplice?

Comment: Che intendi, @entonio? Sono scritte come le abbiamo scritte: “così”, “chiuso” etc.

Comment: Non sono sicuro di aver capito bene la tua domanda, @entonio, ma /s/ e /ss/ (o meglio /s:/) sono suoni diversi: per esempio “resa” e “ressa” sono parole diverse con una pronuncia diversa.

Comment: Scuse @DaG, per un attimo lo dimenticai. C'è quindi distinzione tra /s/ -s-, /z/ (anche) -s- o -z-, /s:/ -ss-, e /z:/ -zz-. In quanto -s- /z/ sembra lo sviluppo logico della -S- latina, stavo cercando di capire l'origine della pronuncia /s/. Così < QVO SIC aveva S-, non -S-; Ma chiuso < CLAVSVS.... e chiese < QUAESIVIT, potrebbe essere il caso che la -S- dopo dittongo viene -s-, non -z- (anche se AV / AE sono altrimenti lo stesso che O: / E: )?

Comment: Tuttavia, è molto interessante quello che spiega l'[articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/pronuncia-s) che ha trovato @antonio.

Answer (score -1):

Non comprendo la tua  insegnante.
Queste questioni pertengono la dizione e dipendono dalla regione in cui ti trovi.
Non esistono regole, salvo rari casi, come "pesca", dove, a seconda dell'apertura/chiusura della "e", cambia il significato della parola.
Diverso sarebbe se tu volessi imparare l'accento di una particolare regione.

### Update

A quanti pensano di avere solide certezze in materia di dizione, sottoporrei il pensiero dell'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it)

A beneficio degli stranieri,  che potrebbero non [conoscerla](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/laccademia):

> In Italia e nel mondo l'Accademia della Crusca è uno dei principali punti di riferimento per le ricerche sulla lingua italiana. La sua attività presente punta a
>   [...]
>   diffondere [...] la *coscienza critica* dell'evoluzione attuale [della nostra lingua], nel quadro degli scambi interlinguistici del mondo contemporaneo.

Venendo alla  pronuncia della `s`,  l'Accademia [parla di](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/pronuncia-s)

> perplessità sulla esatta pronuncia [della *s*] in alcune parole

e il motivo sta in ciò che il nostro

> sistema grafico ha fornito soltanto un grafema, un segno, per indicare sia la variante sorda che la sonora, lasciando quindi nell'incertezza i parlanti non toscani [...] (una situazione analoga a quella delle vocali e e o aperte o chiuse).

Non bisogna dimenticare che soltanto in tempi recenti ci siamo dotati di  mezzi audio per diffondere la pronuncia corretta, ma all'indomani dell'unità d'Italia,  l'italiano ufficiale si poteva veicolare

> a partire dal modello fiorentino *soltanto per scritto*, sulla base dei testi dei grandi scrittori e dei vocabolari, lasciando una *perenne incertezza sull'esatta pronuncia* di alcune parole che presentavano la `s`

Anche le persone colte, dunque, si trovavano in difficoltà: costoro sapevano  che la `s` latina era sempre sorda, ma non potevano sapere quando, nel passaggio all'italiano fiorentino,  dovevano sonorizzarla, appunto per la mancanza di specifici grafemi nei vocabolari, e stesso dicasi per le vocali aperte e chiuse.

Dal fiorentino si è passato ufficialmente al romano durante il ventennio. Questa fase è cruciale, in quanto è noto che una lingua parlata si diffonde tramite radio, prima, cinema e  televisione poi, e in Italia tutte queste strutture furono ubicate da Mussolini in Roma, in particolare la nostra Hollywood, Cinecittà.

Ma qual era dizione "suggerita" dal regime per la "s" o per le altre  ambiguità menzionate dalla Crusca?
Basta consultare il *Prontuario di pronuncia e di ortografia* di Bertoni e Ugolini, imposto come manuale ufficiale della radio.

> I. Quando Firenze si accorda, come avviene quasi sempre, con Roma, si accetterà la pronunzia fiorentina e romana (per es. néve, fórno, mòdo, ecc.)
>   II. Questa pronunzia sarà accolta anche quando le altre città toscane non si accordino con Firenze (per es. nève a Siena, Pisa, ecc. contro néve di Firenze)
>   III. Quando Roma non si accordi con Firenze, due strade ci stanno aperte dinanzi: o accettare, sull'esempio dei nostri attori, la pronunzia fiorentina colta, come quella della culla della nostra lingua letteraria, ovvero accettare la pronunzia colta di Roma, come quella della Capitale in cui si foggia, con la storia, la lingua della patria
>   *Noi proponiamo la pronunzia della capitale*. [...] Siamo convinti che, mentre la pronunzia di Firenze ha per sé il passato, quella di Roma ha per sé l'avvenire

La scelta linguistica del regime, unitamente all'ubicazione delle strutture ove venivano reclutate le "voci", spiega quale possa essere la pronuncia  che a tutt'oggi viene insegnata nelle varie scuole di dizione.

Ovviamente con l'avvento dei sintetizzatori vocali il problema si ripropone. A quale stile mai si rifarà il vocabolario menzionato della nostra OP? Utilizza le vocali aperte di Milano o quelle chiuse di Roma?

Trattandosi di un dizionario RAI, cioè del servizio radiotelevisivo di Stato, sarebbe facile dire che ha optato per pronuncie tipiche della città che  "ha per sé l'avvenire".
In realtà, il problema è più complesso, in quanto per i casi ambigui come quelli presentati da @Charo,  un sintetizzatore audio deve per forza operare una scelta: "chiudo" o "apro"? "sonorizzo" o no? 
Quando nemmeno l'Accademia della Crusca sa come regolarsi, la scelta più semplice è quella di restare nel solco della tradizione.

Tuttavia, per quel che riguarda i parlanti, italiani o stranieri che siano, il "discorso" (è appunto il caso di dire) è ben diverso.   Oggi, per fortuna, non siamo piu soggetti al *Manuale* si è fatta strada una versione *non normativa* della lingua, alternativa a quella dei cosiddetti "puristi".

Spero che ciò chiarisca, senza troppi inutili tecnicismi, il peso anche storico della dizione nella nostra lingua, non  sminuendone il valore.

Concluderei dicendo che, per qualsiasi esame, è sempre bene attenersi ai *desiderata* del docente.  Superato l'esame di italiano,  come suggerito dagli Accademici della Crusca, è bene sviluppare una "coscienza critica della sua evoluzione attuale".

(I corsivi nelle citazioni sono miei)

Comment: Evidentemente l'insegnante ha sbagliato a proposito di una di quelle parole, ma a parte questo la fonetica e l'ortoepia di una lingua (in questo caso l'italiano standard) ne sono parte a tutti gli effetti e non vedo perché non vadano insegnate. E, sì, esistono regole: hai mai notato che tutti i vocabolari, usando l'IPA o altre convenzioni, denotano le s e le z sorde e sonore, i raddoppiamenti sintattici, l'apertura delle vocali, la posizione dell'accento tonico etc?

Comment: Sembra che questi aspetti siano importanti per la parte orale dell'esame che dovrò fare alla fine del corso (livello C1).

Comment: Ed io che pensavo di essere una persona che conosce la propria lingua, in quanto usa correttamente vocaboli e congiuntivi... A questo punto ritengo di essere profondamente ignorante, ma dubito che inizierò a studiare la fonetica dell'italiano, e mi terrò il mio accento settentrionale per quanto concerne le varie "s"