# La pronuncia standard dell'italiano è effettivamente cambiata, ed in particolare, si è "settentrionalizzata"?

Tags: pronunciation

Recentemente ho iniziato a prendere lezioni di dizione da un'attrice diplomata, per correggere la cadenza dialettale (meridionale) ed alcuni vezzi di pronuncia. Ebbene, molti degli errori che mi sono stati segnalati me li aspettavo, ma dopo aver riascoltato a casa la registrazione della prova di lettura, sono rimasto basito nel notare che non avevo azzeccato neanche una *s* intervocalica - o meglio, solo quelle che per assonanza con correzioni precedenti, ho intuito di dover rendere **sonore**: ad esempio tutti gli /-ozo/, /-eze/, forme del passato remoto come *misero* > /ˈmizero/ e *casa* > /kaza/.
Cercando online ho realizzato che nel Centro-sud, Toscana e Sardegna escluse, la *s* intervocalica è sempre sorda - lascito della pronuncia classica del latino, in cui la *s* non è **mai sonora**.

La pagina Wikipedia sulla [S sorda](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_sorda#cite_ref-5) afferma che la pronuncia standard dell'italiano si basa difatti su quella toscana (ed è ciò che immaginavo), "intermedia e più variata sia di quella settentrionale che di quella centro-meridionale". Ponendo come regola la sonorizzazione della sibilante intervocalica, riporta cinque casistiche di eccezioni, ovvero **laddove si ha la sorda /s/**. Tra queste, in contraddizione con quanto appreso nella mia prima lezione:

> - Nei suffissi derivativi -ese per gli etnici (inglese, milanese ecc.; eccezione: francese, che ha la sonora), e -oso e -osa di aggettivi e sostantivi (glorioso, affettuoso, maroso ecc.), comprese le parole da questi derivate (cineseria, gloriosamente, gloriosissimo, affettuosità ecc.);
> - Nelle desinenze sigmatiche del passato remoto e del participio passato di alcuni verbi irregolari -esi, -ese, -esero, -eso; -osi, -ose, -osero, -oso (resi, rese, resero, reso; e scesi ecc., difesi ecc. ...; e nascosi ecc., posi ecc. ...; ma esplosi ecc. con la sonora);
> - In alcune parole isolate (e ovviamente nei loro derivati), di cui le più comuni sono: casa, chiusi e chiuso (con socchiusi e socchiuso, ecc.), cosa, così, mese, naso, peso, Pisa, posa e posare, raso, risi e riso (in tutti i significati; anche sorrisi e sorriso).

A questo punto ho approfondito la ricerca, e ho scoperto che i sociolinguisti parlano di *ristandardizzazione* dell'italiano, ossia l'instaurazione di un *italiano neostandard* che avvicina lo scritto e il parlato della lingua, con fenomeni morfosintattici noti a tutti (ad esempio *egli, ella, essi* soppiantati da *lui, lei, loro*) ma anche relativi alla pronuncia:

> rispetto alla realizzazione toscana di casa, [ˈkaːsa], e noioso, [noˈjoːso], attori e annunciatori «tendono a “settentrionalizzare”, generalizzando la sonora» (Serianni, 1988, p. 35: dunque, [ˈkaːza] e [noˈjoːzo]); è così che si pronuncia sempre più spesso, «un po’ dovunque» (Serianni 1988, p. 36), [ˈdziːo] e [ˈdzukːero], di contro alla resa normativa toscana, con affricata alveolare sorda, [ˈtsiːo] e [ˈtsukːero], ancora seguita dalla maggior parte dei dizionari.
>
> (Un estratto dell'articolo [*La nozione coseriana di dialetto e le sue implicazioni per l'area italoromanza*](https://iris.unito.it/retrieve/handle/2318/1660648/391535/Regis%20-%20Dialetti_revised%20version%20%5B27.5.2016%5D.pdf) di Riccardo Regis)

Nello stesso articolo si può leggere quella che sembra essere una risposta negativa alla mia domanda nel titolo (il grassetto è mio):

> L’italiano standard letterario (il ‘vecchio’ standard) e l’italiano neostandard (il ‘nuovo’ standard) convivono nello schema di architettura dell’italiano contemporaneo di Berruto (1987, p. 21), **con il primo che manifesta un maggiore grado di formalità, senza tuttavia arretrare, rispetto al secondo**. Ai nostri fini, è interessante che Berruto (1987, p. 23–24) fornisca come etichetta «quasi sinonimica» di italiano neostandard quella di italiano regionale colto medio, che a sua volta è da considerarsi equipollente a italiano regionale standard: mentre italiano neostandard pone «l’accento sugli aspetti unitari, soprattutto morfosintattici, che costituiscono la larga base comune degli impieghi dell’italiano da ritenere normali presso parlanti colti», italiano regionale colto medio evidenzia l’emergere «della differenziazione geografica che sarà percepibile nella gran maggioranza degli utenti» e nel contempo il fatto che «si può ora affermare che ci siano degli italiani regionali standard che costituiscono lo standard di ogni singola area».

Ora, analizzando le indicazioni, univoche, del Dizionario Italiano multimediale di Ortografia e Pronunzia [(DOP)](http://www.dizionario.rai.it) si perviene alla stessa conclusione, e cioè si ritrovano regola ed eccezioni mostrate dalla pagina Wikipedia che ho linkato all'inizio. D'altra parte, non è così per il Dizionario di Pronuncia Italiana online [(DiPI)](http://www.dipionline.it/dizionario/) che fa capo a Luciano Canepari, professore di Fonetica e fonologia all'Università di Venezia: la sibilante intervocalica sonora viene sempre inserita nel campo "*pronuncia moderna*: la piú consigliabile", mentre quella sorda, nei casi di interesse (vedi Wikipedia), è la pronuncia "tradizionale: la piú consigliata un tempo".

Infine, molti siti (tutti?) che propongono corsi di dizione online arrivano a sostenere qualcosa come: (il grassetto è mio)

> La "S" aspra o sorda italiana si presenta nei seguenti casi:
>
> - Quando si trova in principio di vocabolo ed è seguita da vocale.
> - Quando è iniziale del secondo componente di un vocabolo composto
> - Quando è doppia
> - Quando è preceduta da consonante, eccetto nei vocaboli con prefisso "trans-" che vogliono la *s* dolce o sonora.
> - Quando è seguita dalle consonanti cosiddette sorde "c", "f", "p", "q", "t".
>
> Nota Bene: alcuni dizionari fonetici stabiliscono che il suono della "s" debba essere aspro anche in molti altri casi come casa, cosa, così, mese, naso, peso, cinese, piemontese, goloso, bisognoso e altri. In realtà **questo tipo di pronuncia è caduta quasi del tutto in disuso, fatta eccezione per qualche parlata dell'Italia centrale e meridionale**.

In relazione al discorso di Regis nel suo articolo, è importante notare che tra questi siti, http://www.bellascuola.it (che ho citato qui sopra) non è legato al mondo del doppiaggio, bensì "è rivolto agli insegnanti che operano nei corsi di lingua italiana dei C.P.I.A e agli stranieri che frequentano corsi di lingua italiana".

---

Qualcuno riesce a sbrogliare la matassa?

Comment: Ottima domanda! Un problema è che una vera e propria pronuncia "standard" dell'italiano non è mai davvero esistita in quanto la diffusione della lingua è stata (almeno prima della televisione) quasi sempre tramite il mezzo scritto. Certo, vi erano spesso indicazioni, ma la fonetica italiana è sempre stata molto "fluida" anche perché nessun parlante madrelingua (nemmeno i fiorentini :P) ha mai davvero realizzato questa mitica "pronuncia standard". Perciò, anche in contesti colti, si è spesso lasciato molto spazio a pronuncie regionali, basate sulla fonetica del substrato. Tieni anche (cont)

Comment: (cont) conto che la *s* intervocalica sonora è andata diffondendosi nell'Italia centrale da prima del 1200 (spesso in voci dotte ed ecclesiastiche, vedi e.g. *chiesa*, M. Maiden congettura che questo sia dovuto ad un influsso di prelati settentrionali), per cui questo potrebbe essere interpretato come una semplice continuazione del trend, per regolarizzazione (e.g. poiché molte *s* intervocaliche sono sonore, rendiamole tutte sonore per semplificare)

Comment: @Denis: Concordo che la pronuncia "standard" (e qui _standard_ è di difficile definizione, ho letto) è artificiosa: nessuno la sviluppa nativamente, proprio perché frutto di una purificazione del tosco-fiorentino. Però la forma astratta esiste, e con lo studio "qualcuno" (diciamo attori/doppiatori d'eccezione) può a priori farla propria. La mia domanda è quindi se questa forma astratta è cambiata. Giustamente parli di regolarizzazione, semplificazione -mi chiedo se questo sia un fenomeno che ha intaccato quella "forma astratta",o se comunque ne ha creata un'altra parallela, ormai da preferire.

Comment: Quando parlo di "forme astratte parallele", faccio riferimento all'articolo di Regis. Solo che lui afferma che la "vecchia" non è stata soppiantata, mentre il DiPI afferma che comunque la "nuova" è quella più consigliabile.

Comment: Penso che questa pronuncia neostandard fosse quella della [mia insegnante d'italiano](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7875/707).

Comment: @Charo: Probabilmente sì - altrimenti, se l'insegnante era del Nord, possibile anche fosse propriamente un vezzo regionale (rispetto allo standard), come Paolo aveva accennato nei commenti alla tua domanda.

Comment: Penso che il cinema e la radio abbiano avuto un ruolo prima della televisione nel definire uno standard diffuso a livello popolare. Oggi ancora i mezzi di comunicazione di massa sono il riferimento di molti per orientarsi nella pronuncia "standard" dell'italiano. Con la nascita delle emittenti locali e il prevalere delle tv private settentironali a livello nazionale probabilmente la pronuncia settentrionale ha avuto un maggiore spazio, e quindi una maggiore diffusione. Oggi penso che la maggiore diversificazione dei canali di comunicazione renda ancora più difficile definire uno standard.

Comment: @CasaMich: A mio modo di vedere, morfologia e sintassi del "neostandard" sono effettivamente le più consigliabili, almeno nel parlato - non è così invece per la pronuncia, a dispetto di quanto afferma il DiPI. In altre parole, ad esempio "lui" ha del tutto soppiantato "egli" in ogni parte d'Italia, mentre non è così per questioni fonetiche come la _s_ intervocalica -stando a quanto ho letto anche sul forum della Crusca, è una tendenza/moda, guidata dal fatto che (come dici tu) diversi canali di comunicazione sono ubicati al Nord, ed in generale il modo di parlare settentrionale,(cont)

Comment: (cont) e spesso milanese in particolare, è percepito come più "elevato" in quanto associato alla ricchezza dell'area/città. Tuttavia, in quanto tendenza appunto, non è effettivamente più consigliabile della pronuncia _standard_, quella più legata alla pronuncia toscana - dove e.g. _casa_ > [kasa].
Almeno non ancora. Non riesco però a trovare riscontri espliciti nella letteratura, stavo pensando di scrivere una mail al professor Canepari. Cosa ne pensi? @CasaMich

Answer (score 2):

Non sono sicuro se questa sia davvero una risposta alla domanda, ma in mancanza d'altro un interessante punto da notare è il libro di Lepschy, Lepschy, *The Italian Language Today*. È un libro inteso come grammatica di riferimento per coloro che apprendono la lingua, anche se sospetto non pochi madrelingua beneficerebbero dalla sua lettura, e scritto da due eminenti linguisti italiani (è presente anche in edizioni italiana e tedesca, ma ahimè io ho solo accesso alla seconda edizione inglese del 1988, che credo comunque la più aggiornata). Nella prefazione scrivono

> We aim at presenting educated Italian not as it is prescribed in grammars and dictionaries, but as it is actually written and spoken. For those aspects in which there does not seem to be a unitary national standard, we have followed northern usage, which seems to us to enjoy most prestige. We aim at enabling foreign students to understand a wide range of expressions and to select those which are most suitable for them to use, in speech or writing. Where necessary we have characterized certain usages as formal or informal, colloquial or literary, or typical of certain parts of the country.

Nella sezione sulla pronuncia, riguardo alla pronuncia della -s- intervocalica

> The alveolar sibilant is [...] voiced ([z]) [...] intervocalically, as in casa [káza] 'house', naso [názo] 'nose'. This last condition can be waived when the intervocalic sibilant is morpheme initial, as in trasognato 'dreamy', presentire 'to have a premonition', risanare 'to heal', etc., which are usually pronounced with a voiceless [s].

Su questa loro scelta (senza dubbio diversa dallo "standard" come immaginato un tempo ), commentano

> These proposals incorporate the aspects of Florentine phonology which have become national, and disregard those which have remained parochial. If the reader prefers to adopt Florentine phonology in its integrity, he can ignore the present section and refer to chapter IV. 1 (a)(i) [...].
>
> We are trying to provide foreign students with a phonological system which has the following advantages over those proposed by puristic grammars: firstly, it is more faithfully represented by conventional spelling; secondly, it is nearer to an overall national system as it ignores phonemic oppositions which are treated differently in different varieties of Italian; thirdly, where a choice has to be made between conflicting varieties, it leans towards a northern standard, which enjoys high prestige, is gaining ground in the country as a whole, and sounds less parochial than other varieties. This we believe to be a fact concerning actual linguistic behaviour
> and linguistic attitudes in Italy, notwithstanding the purely theoretical homage still paid to Tuscan pronunciation.

Sembra che Lepschy e Lepschy ritengano alcune caratteristiche settentrionali sufficientemente diffuse nel territorio italiano da consigliarne l'uso anche a coloro che apprendono la lingua, perché più simile a come la maggioranza degli italiani parlano. Ovviamente questa non è necessariamente una scelta universale, ma è un'altra indicazione che la pronuncia "standard" dell'italiano stia cambiando.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta, userò questo spunto insieme ad altri per scriverne una mia. Vorrei solo precisare che non è veritiero che la maggioranza degli italiani generalizza la sonorizzazione della _s_ intervocalica. Segue dal fatto che la quasi-totalità dei centromeridionali, anche di alto livello culturale, non lo fa -tra essi, c'è chi generalizza la sorda, e chi è più o meno vicino allo standard toscano. Sono relativamente pochi, e recenti, i casi in cui si possa osservare la nuova tendenza in tale macrogruppo.Per questo si parla di un _neostandard_ che affianca ma non sostituisce lo standard

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Aspetto con attenzione la tua risposta, specialmente se hai a tua disposizione degli studi sulla fonetica regionale (che sembrano purtroppo rari). Va detto che Lepschy e Lepschy sono entrambi dall'Italia settentrionale (Torino e Venezia) e in particolare Giulio Lepschy sembra avere una certa tenerezza verso il *venexian* (perfettamente comprensibile da parte mia :)), anche se spero che questo non abbia influenzato troppo la stesura del libro.

Comment: (_Jùsto_! ;D) Potrà volerci del tempo ma spero di trovare qualcosa!

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Controllando oggi ho trovato anche questo [illuminante articolo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronuncia_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) nell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani. Si tratta per lo più di una discussione storica su come la pronuncia dell'italiano si sia evoluta ma contiene abbondanti spunti di riflessione